# Comfortable mexican sofa - how the assets are served?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, content-management-system, ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline, comfortable-mexican-sofa

One of the impressive features  in [Comfortable Mexican Sofa](https://github.com/comfy/comfortable-mexican-sofa) is editing `js` and `stylesheets` online. There is no need to deploy each time the assets are changed. I suppose `javascript` and `stylesheets` code is stored in database.

I am curious if those assets are precompiled and served by the pipeline, like regular assets in a Rails application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are served as a normal controller/action response. Run `rake routes` and take a look at `cms_content_css` and `cms_content_js` paths. So there's an overhead compared to serving precompiled assets. This is not an issue with relatively low traffic sites, but when server load is a concern you probably want to implement some sort of caching.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it really helped me. Your work is amazing.I have a suggestion: there should be a tag `comfortable-mexican-sofa` here in StackOverflow

Comment: Thanks! Actually I can't create `comfortable-mexican-sofa` tag because I need at least 1500 reputation... but you can if you edit your question.

Comment: Thank you for allowing me to create a tag!